# How Do I install and use fluxbox window manager?

Tags: installation, 10.04, window-manager, fluxbox

I am using backtrack 5 r3 which is based off ubuntu 10.04 lts. I want to use the fluxbox windows manager if possible. I already tried apt-get install fluxbox, which appeared to work, but I have no clue where it installed to or what to do once I find the installed files. Is there an executable file that I click on? or can I just open it from the terminal?

Also would openbox be a better alternative to fluxbox? would that answer depend on the users needs?

I would have moved this to a discussion but do not know how. I think I am getting some kind of error. the output of `/usr/bin/fluxbox` is:

```
Failed to read: session.ignoreBorder
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.forcePseudoTransparency
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.colorsPerChannel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.doubleClickInterval
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabPadding
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.styleFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.styleOverlay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.slitlistFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.appsFile
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabsAttachArea
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheLife
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.cacheMax
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.autoRaiseDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.opaqueMove
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.fullMaximization
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxIgnoreIncrement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxDisableMove
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.maxDisableResize
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.workspacewarping
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.showwindowposition
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.autoRaise
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.clickRaises
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.defaultDeco
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.rootCommand
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tab.placement
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.windowMenu
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.noFocusWhileTypingDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.followModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.userFollowModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.workspaces
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.edgeSnapThreshold
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.window.focus.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.window.unfocus.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menu.alpha
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menuDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menuDelayClose
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tab.width
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tooltipDelay
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.menuMode
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.overlay.lineWidth
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.overlay.lineStyle
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.overlay.joinStyle
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.overlay.capStyle
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.allowRemoteActions
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.clientMenu.usePixmap
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.usePixmap
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.maxOver
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabs.intitlebar
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.tabFocusModel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.focusNewWindows
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.rowPlacementDirection
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.colPlacementDirection
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.screen0.windowPlacement
Setting default value
BScreen::BScreen: an error occured while querying the X server.
    another window manager already running on display:0.0
Error: Couldn't find screens to manage.
Make sure you don't have another window manager running.
```

I would have made that more neat if I knew how

Comment: To locate the binary file of fluxbox, type `which fluxbox`.

Comment: I found it it was /usr/bin/fluxbox. When I try to click on it nothing happens. I dragged it over to the terminal and it tried to run but mentioned that another windows manager was already running. Do I have to go into a non gui mode to switch the windows manager, or can it be done from the terminal?

Comment: To run it type `/usr/bin/fluxbox` on the terminal.

Comment: Most questions about non-official Ubuntu derivatives are classified as *off-topic*. This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions about non-official Ubuntu distributions (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a page with a guide. http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Fluxbox_Install. You just have to follow these commands:

```
apt-get install flux-for-back
echo exec /usr/bin/startfluxbox > ~/.xinitrc
shutdown -r 0
```

In order to revert back to the default WM all you have to do is delete the .xinitrc file.

```
rm -rf ~/.xinitrc
shutdown -r 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To run fluxbox you first log out, then select fluxbox from the log in screen (there should be a menu somewhere) and log back in.

To run from a terminal

```
startx startfluxbox
```

If you can not find fluxbox in the log in screen, ask on the backtrack support sites (mailing list, etc). Questions on non-ubuntu distros, inculding backtrack, are considered off topic here and I suspect this question will soon be closed.

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/a-5-minute-guide-to-fluxbox/

Comment: backtrack does not have a graphical log-in page. you log in using command line and then use the startx command to get to the GUI. I only asked this question here because every time I start backtrack it shows the pink screen with 10.04 booting up, then it goes to backtracks command line. Plus I usually seem to get good answers from here. Whether it will work for me or not I appreciate the link, it looks like I can learn a lot from there. Thank you.

Comment: I understand, but ... backtrack is not Ubuntu, it is highly customized and 10.04 is beyond end of life. For both reasons, support here is minimal. Hope you enjoy fluxbox.